# Connect to SQL Server using hostednetwork from Internet

Tags: sql, sql-server

1. My connection is Modem ROUTER -> MyPC -> Laptop (**laptop** is connected wireless using hostednetwork from **MyPC**)
2. I install SQL Server on both **Mypc** and **laptop**
3. On my modem router I have configured port forwarding 1433 and 1434 to **MyPC**
4. My goal is connect on **laptop** using public IP address.
5. I check what is my public address from **MyPC** and **laptop** but the result is same IP address for both of them. And I try to connect using public IP address but it always connect to **MyPc** SQL Server.
6. How to connect to **laptop** to SQL Server ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind I have figure out. this exactly what im doing:

1. my **modem Router** Public IP is 36.80.250.25 and the **Modem Router** local ip is 192.168.123.1  and **Modem router** ip forwarding setting on port 1433 to **MyPc** (192.168.123.2).
2. **Mypc** lan card IP 192.168.123.2 and **Mypc** wireless Lan card IP 192.168.137.1 and also i open windows 7 firewall to accept incoming SQL server and SQL Brrowser connection.
3. **Laptop** IP 192.168.137.2. I set static ip address. and set the sql server listening port to 14330.
4. So **Mypc** is act as router, listening sql request on port 1433 and foward the request to port 14330 on the **Laptop** with this command via cmd.exe:

   ```
   netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=1433 listenaddress=0.0.0.0 connectport=14330 connectaddress=192.168.137.2
   ```
5. So i test it using SQL Server Management Studio Express and connect to 36.80.250.25 just using IP address and it can connect to **laptop** SQL sever.